# malloc debugging...solution needed

Tags: c, malloc

```
typedef struct nodes* nods;
        struct nodes
            {
                int field,grammi,stili,flag1,flag_gv,height;
                nods d,r,l,u;
            };
```

.
.
.

```
int j;

         struct nodes kefelement[30];
        kefelement=(nods)malloc(30*(sizeof(struct nodes)));
            for ((j=0); (j<30); j++)   
               {
                kefelement[j].r=NULL;
                kefelement[j].d=NULL;
                kefelement[j].grammi=j+1;
                kefelement[j].stili=j+1;
                kefelement[j].field=0;
                kefelement[j].u=NULL;
                kefelement[j].l=NULL;
                kefelement[j].flag1=0;
                kefelement[j].flag_gv=0;
                kefelement[j].height=0;

            }
```

the problem is with the malloc....someone pls help me!!!!

Comment: This is nothing to do with `malloc`; you cannot assign to an array type.

Comment: Definitely a confusion between static and dynamic array creation.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct nodes kefelement[30];
kefelement = (nods)malloc(30*(sizeof(struct nodes)));
```

`kefelement` is an array. The compiler will allocate a region of memory that can be accessed through the name `kefelement`. Note that this name is not a pointer that can be assigned a new value. However, using `kefelement` in an expression will (with some exceptions) translate the name to a pointer to its first element.

If you want to allocate dynamic memory for the array, you need to declare it as a pointer:

```
struct nodes *kefelement;
kefelement = (nods)malloc(30*(sizeof(struct nodes)));
```

or better:

```
kefelement = malloc (30 * sizeof *kefelement);
```

The last version automatically allocates the correct amount of memory, regardless of what the pointer points to. The `(nods)` cast is not necessary in C.

Comment: so actually just leaving this as it is without the malloc (cause i do not need a dynamic array) i will not have problems parsing this matrix along to other routines??? cause my project is to store a sparse array so these kefelements are simply the coordinates!!
thnx anyway for your help it's been enlightening!!

Comment: @VasilisLi: Yes, that should be fine.